# Calling a struct in a class from main in C++

Tags: c++

I have a header file with a class and a struct in it, but I can't figure out how to call it from main.

```
class TestDetails {
public:
  struct User{
  std::string username;
  std::string password;
  };
};
```

How do I call the following from main,and store a struct into a vector so I can
pass into a text file?

Comment: what do you want to call exactly?

Comment: "Calling" is what you do with functions (or function-like objects). If I have a function called `foo`, then `foo()` calls that function. You can't call a `struct`.

Comment: Yes you can. "struct! come over here!"

Comment: "Hello? Yes this is `struct`."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If by "calling a struct" you mean instantiating it, then knowing that the type is `TestDetails::User`, you simply need to create a `vector<TestDetails::User>`. Then you can fill it up with objects like you would do with any other type. For example,

```
// instantiate a vector with two users
std::vector<TestDetails::User> v{{"bob", "1234"}, 
                                 {"alice", "alice_psswd"}};

// add another user
v.push_back({"trudy", "****"});
```

Comment: @user657267 I am not convinced my understanding of the question is the same as OP's ;-)

Comment: @user657267: Well... "how to call the struct", you call it `TestDetails::User`. I think it's at least grammatically correct.

Comment: @KerrekSB That's actually an excellent point, my brain has hardwired "call" into meaning run something in programming contexts, and the other meaning was completely lost on me (and others it would seem...).

Comment: I wanted to instantiate a vector and add a struct into a vector, then outputting a vector's values(that a user inputs) to a text file.

Comment: What about adding variables that a user entered to a vector? 

I don't really understand structs and vectors, as I intended to enter user's variables to a vector(if possible),then output the values to a text file.

Comment: @Zenix There are many questions here about reading user input into variables, and writing them out to files.